# OOM uploading a large amount of .tif - aerial imagery ot PostGIS with python

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, geotiff-tiff, psycopg2

I'm trying to upload our big dataset of aerial imagery on our server via python and psycopg2

The function I use for this task is:

```
def load_into_PostGIS(connection, image_path):
    with open(image_path, 'rb') as f:
        with connection: 
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO remote_sensing.aerial_imagery(rast) VALUES (ST_FromGDALRaster(%s))", (f.read(),))
```

Uploading up to 3 of these around 5 MB. sized .tiff-files works with no issues. After that, it's impossible to open them in qgis and actually raises an OOM-Error after some while when I run "`load_into_PostGIS`" with `.apply` on my pandas Dataframe containing all the files paths.

What am I missing here that uploads those file obviously not the way I need them?

**Edit**:
Instead of using the funky python Insert statement I use raster2pgsql:

```
    cmd = f"""
            set PGPASSWORD={pw}&&SET PATH=%PATH%;{bin_path}&& "raster2pgsql.exe" -I -C "{main_path}\dop*.tif" -F {schema}.dop20_rgb_utm32_{folder} | psql -U {user} -d {dbname} -h {host} -p {port}
           """
```

Comment: why not use raster2pgsql?

Comment: I'm doing it with it now, but now ran into the issue that batch uploading gives every .tif the same file_name. See edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using raster2pgsql solved my issues mostly:

`bin_path` is the path to the raster2pgsql.exe which should be in C:\Program Files\PostgresSQL\13\bin

```
cmd = f"""
            set PGPASSWORD={pw}&&SET PATH=%PATH%;{bin_path}&& "raster2pgsql.exe" -I -C "{main_path}\dop*.tif" -F {schema}.dop20_rgb_utm32_{folder} | psql -U {user} -d {dbname} -h {host} -p {port}
       """
```